# Using multiple listbox in noncontiguous ranges

Tags: vba, dynamic, listbox

I am working with a schedule, that I have imported and formatted into my workbook.

I am wanting this to populate Phase in the upper listbox and then when a phase is selected the sub-task associated with those phases are displayed in the bottom listbox.

I want to use an array but I seem to be having problems when the columns are not next to each other or there are "gaps" with the blank cells.

My first attempt using assigning the Array to the currentregion worked but brought all columns and fields in. Listbox1 should contain (ID, PHASE NAME, DURATION, START DATE, FINISH DATE) List box 2 should when a Phase is selected contain the subtasks if any from the column to the right, listed before the next next Phase name. (ID, SUB-TASK NAME, DURATION, START DATE, FINISH DATE)

(See picture)

I have code but its more me trouble-shooting than an actual semi working script.

```
Dim shT As Worksheet
Dim schnumrng1 As Range
Dim schnumrng2 As Range
Dim schnumrng3 As Range
Dim schnumrng4 As Range
Dim schnumrng5 As Range
Dim schpersonrng As Range
Dim schphaserng As Range
Dim schlistrng As Range
Dim maxschnum
Dim schstatus
Dim schperson
Dim schlistnum
Dim Ar() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim lc

'allowevents = True


''Set Screen parameters
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.EnableEvents = False
'
Worksheets("Schedule").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Schedule").Activate
'
Set shT = Worksheets("Schedule")
 maxschnum = shT.Cells(shT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 Set schnumrng = Range("B5", "B" & maxschnum)
 
 'Set Ranges for the list box
Set schnumrng1 = Range("A5", "A" & maxschnum)
Set schnumrng2 = Range("B5", "B" & maxschnum)
Set schnumrng3 = Range("D5", "D" & maxschnum)
Set schnumrng4 = Range("E5", "E" & maxschnum)
Set schnumrng5 = Range("F5", "F" & maxschnum)

 
'This is static and not moving to the next line in my for statement / switched to named ranges and errors
Set rng = schnumrng1, schnumrng2, schnumrng3, schnumrng4, schnumrng5
'Set rng = Range("A5,B5,D5,E5,F5")

    i = 1
    j = 1
For Each lc In schnumrng
    If lc <> vbNullString Then
        For Each cl In rng
            ReDim Preserve Ar(1, 1 To i)
            Ar(j, i) = cl.Value
            
            i = i + 1
            Next cl
        Else
        End If
        j = j + 1
Next lc

    With ScheduleForm.SchMainTasklt
        .ColumnCount = i - 1
        .ColumnWidths = "50;150;50;50;50"
        .List = Ar
    End With
```

My problem then is two fold, trying to use the dynamic ranges or another tool Index? collection? to populate the 1st list box. 2. How to deal with blanks and noncontiguous columns when data is not separated for organization purposes.

[image: Sheet schedule that is imported and code ran from]

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. It would be difficult to express the result with the user form, so it would be good to explain how to get the data on the sheet.

Comment: I am trying to put columns ABDEF in one list box using an array, based on the rows with values in column B.  however can't seem to add multicolumns to the list box. currently my code has dynamic ranges for the columns set to another range and this is not working.

Then im trying to do a 2nd list box for Columns ACDEF, based on the select made in the first list box, using an array but i have the same issue as the 1st listbox with using a dynamic range plus the blanks in column C cause issues when i try to use a range. I hope that is a little more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I figured out your intentions well.

1. First, only the data in column b, not empty cells, is extracted from listbox1.
2. Second, when listbox1 is selected, data related to listbox2 is collected through the selected listbox value.

### Module Code

Place this code in the module. This is because global variables must be used.

```
Public vDB As Variant
Public Dic As Object 'Dictionary
Sub test()
    Dim shT As Worksheet
    Dim maxschnum As Long
    Dim Ar() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim vC() As Variant
    Dim cnt As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim s As String, s2 As String
    


    Worksheets("Schedule").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Schedule").Activate
    '
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  'New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Set shT = Worksheets("Schedule")
    
    
    maxschnum = shT.Cells(shT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With shT
        vDB = .Range("a5", .Range("f" & maxschnum))
    End With
    
    'vC is data colum A,B,D,E,F
    vC = Array(1, 2, 4, 5, 6)
    
    s2 = vDB(2, 2)
    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        s = vDB(i, 2) 'column B
        If s = "" Then
            n = n + 1
        Else
            If Dic.Exists(s) Then
            Else
                If i > 2 Then
                    Dic(s2) = Dic(s2) & "," & n
                End If
                
                Dic.Add s, i
                s2 = s
                cnt = cnt + 1
                ReDim Preserve Ar(1 To 5, 1 To cnt)
                For c = 0 To UBound(vC)
                    Ar(c + 1, cnt) = vDB(i, vC(c))
                Next c
            End If
            n = 0
        End If
    Next i
    Dic(s2) = Dic(s2) & "," & n
    
    ' Records information about the data in a dictionary.
    ' Dic is "phase neme" is Key, Item is "2,4"
    ' example for KICkOFF
    ' dic key is "KICKOFF",  Item is "5,4"
    '   5 is KICOFF's row number in array vDB
    '   4 is the number of blank cells related to kickoff.

    
        With ScheduleForm.SchMainTasklt
            .ColumnCount = 5
            .ColumnWidths = "50;150;50;60;60"
            .BoundColumn = 2
            '.List = Ar
            .Column = Ar 'In the state that the array has been converted to row column, you can use listbox.column.
        End With
End Sub
```

### Form Code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Call test

End Sub
Private Sub SchMainTasklt_Click()
    Dim s As String, sItem As String
    Dim arr As Variant, vC As Variant
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim st As Long, ed As Long
    Dim iLast As Long, iFirst As Long
    Dim i As Long, n As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    vC = Array(1, 3, 4, 5, 6) 'data colums A,C,D,E,F
    s = SchMainTasklt.Value
    'MsgBox s
    
    sItem = Dic(s)
    arr = Split(sItem, ",")
    
    st = Val(arr(0))
    ed = Val(arr(1))
    
    iFirst = st + 1
    iLast = st + ed
    
    If ed = 0 Then
        MsgBox "no data!!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For i = iFirst To iLast
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
        For j = 0 To UBound(vC)
            vR(j + 1, n) = vDB(i, vC(j))
        Next j
    Next i
    With ListBox2
        .ColumnCount = 5
        .ColumnWidths = "50;150;50;60;60"
        .BoundColumn = 2
        .Column = vR
    End With

End Sub
```

### Result Image

When you click the "KICKOFF" , Show kickoff related data in listbox2.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for showing this. The pic you included appear to  be what i want the code to do. However when trying to apply the code, the form code portion variable 
s = SchMainTasklt.Value is causing a  Run time error 94 "invalid use of null... I changed that to a variant and made it past that section and then  st = Val(arr(0)) & ed = Val(arr(1)) runtime error 9 subscript out of range. I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Worked  well listbox1(SchMainTasklt)?

Comment: Yes listbox1 is named (Name) SchMainTasklt

Comment: @JohnSanders,  Check listbox1  `multiselect=false`

Comment: multiselect for listbox1 is set to single

Comment: @JohnSanders, I'm sorry. However, the cause seems to be a separate problem from my code.

Comment: What a difference a little sleep makes. Your code does in fact work, I copied the "Form Code" and pasted it in the Initialize Form section. I for some reason did not acknowledge you had the Initialize form and the Click event in the same area. 
Thank you I separated the two pieces of code and it appears to work. I will perform some tweaking and this should solve my issue.

Thanks again!!

Comment: @JohnSanders, I am glad that it works well